# Can't login when testing a published Silverlight App

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7.5, silverlight-5.0

I created a Silverlight Business Application and published it.

When I test it from the Internet Explorer, it runs ok but I can't login using the pre-built login interface that comes with the Silverlight Business Application template.

I included ASPNETDB.mdf in the project since it wasn't being generated in iis when publishing (I got this idea from http://sladapter.blogspot.com/2011/02/steps-to-deploy-silverlight-business.html)

I was having a Load operation failed for query login, but now I get this error:

**Error using default 'MembershipProvider'. Make sure it's well configured. Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in impersonating the client. The connection will be closed. Mensaje de InnerException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in impersonating the client. The connection will be closed.**

I'm not tampering with the Web.config, I just create application, build, publish, etc.. I expect that all these configurations are done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to SQL configuration Manager> Make state of the process as running.
2. Now in IIS7, Click on `Application pools` > If it is default pool, Create your other `new Application Pool` pool and keep identity as `LOCAL SYSTEM` instead of built-in system.
3. See if your runs on your own created pool instead of Default and in Local system instead of built-in.

See if it works!!